# Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException The file or directory to be published does not exist: /frontend/web

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

Moved the site from one server to another with postgresql database. Db has been connected. Then I used this command:

```
composer install
```

While loading the site, yii debugger shows an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlxui.png)

What is more, `composer update` shows many errors in console:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Composer\Package\RootPackage::getConfig() in /var/www/907-irbis/data/www/site.ru/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Config/ConfigBuilder.php:111
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/907-irbis/data/www/site.ru/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Config/ConfigBuilder.php(74): Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Config\ConfigBuilder::getConfigBase(Object(Composer\Composer), Object(Composer\IO\ConsoleIO))
#1 /var/www/907-irbis/data/www/site.ru/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/FxpAssetPlugin.php(82): Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Config\ConfigBuilder::build(Object(Composer\Composer), Object(Composer\IO\ConsoleIO))
#2 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(215): Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\FxpAssetPlugin->activate(Object(Composer\Composer), Object(Composer\IO\ConsoleIO))
#3 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(188): Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->addPlugin(Object(Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\FxpAssetPlugin))
#4 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer/PluginInstaller.php(62): Composer\Pl in /var/www/907-irbis/data/www/site.ru/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Config/ConfigBuilder.php on line 111

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Composer\Package\RootPackage::getConfig() in /var/www/907-irbis/data/www/site.ru/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Config/ConfigBuilder.php:111
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/907-irbis/data/www/site.ru/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Config/ConfigBuilder.php(74): Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Config\ConfigBuilder::getConfigBase(Object(Composer\Composer), Object(Composer\IO\ConsoleIO))
#1 /var/www/907-irbis/data/www/site.ru/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/FxpAssetPlugin.php(82): Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\Config\ConfigBuilder::build(Object(Composer\Composer), Object(Composer\IO\ConsoleIO))
#2 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(215): Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\FxpAssetPlugin->activate(Object(Composer\Composer), Object(Composer\IO\ConsoleIO))
#3 /usr/share/php/Composer/Plugin/PluginManager.php(188): Composer\Plugin\PluginManager->addPlugin(Object(Fxp\Composer\AssetPlugin\FxpAssetPlugin))
#4 /usr/share/php/Composer/Installer/PluginInstaller.php(62): Composer\Pl in /var/www/907-irbis/data/www/site.ru/vendor/fxp/composer-asset-plugin/Config/ConfigBuilder.php on line 111
```

Comment: Have you tried first running `composer selfupdate` and `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.3"`

Comment: composer self-update: Command "self-update" is not defined. global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.3 - same errors.

Comment: Have you got composer installed at all?

Comment: When I put files of the site to the directory, I used `composer install` command.

Comment: install composer first and update composer asset plugin `composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.4.2` see [**`here`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/news/148/important-note-about-bower-and-the-asset-plugin/) and make sure you init the environment if you pulled your code from the git repo, using `./yii init`, if you have the composer.phar inside the project directory try adding `php` in the start `php composer.phar install`